# Simple Linear Regression - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am new to ML and tried to build a Linear Regression Model by myself. Object is to predict the fahrenheit values for celcius values.
This is my code:

```
celsius_q = np.array([-40, -10, 0, 8, 15, 22, 38], dtype= float)
fahrenheit_a = np.array([-40, 14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100], dtype = float)

inputs = celsius_q
output_expected = fahrenheit_a

# y = m * x + b
m = 100
b = 0
m_gradient = 0
b_gradient = 0
learning_rate = 0.00001
#Forwardpropagation
for i in range(10000):
    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        m_gradient += (m + (b * inputs[i] - output_expected[i]))
        b_gradient += inputs[i] * (m + (b * inputs[i]) - output_expected[i])

m_new = m - learning_rate * (2/len(inputs)) * m_gradient 
b_new = b - learning_rate * (2/len(inputs)) * b_gradient
```

The code generates wrong weights for m and b, no matter how much I change the learning_rate and the epochs. The weights for minimal loss function has to be:

```
b = 1.8
m = 32
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to update in every descent step, not just at the end.

Comment: You mean m_new and b_new?

Comment: @AoT_1503 Yes. With your code, the weights are updated only once. The correct way would be to update your weights in every step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update of `m` and `b` needs to happen every step but this is not going to be enough. You also need to slightly increase your learning rate, say twice:

```
import numpy as np
celsius_q = np.array([-40, -10, 0, 8, 15, 22, 38], dtype=float)
fahrenheit_a = np.array([-40, 14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100], dtype=float)

inputs = celsius_q
output_expected = fahrenheit_a

# y = m * x + b
m_new = m = 100.0
b_new = b = 0.0
m_gradient = 0.0
b_gradient = 0.0
learning_rate = 0.0002
# Forwardpropagation
for i in range(10000):
    m_gradient, b_gradient = 0, 0

    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        m_gradient += (m_new + (b_new * inputs[i] - output_expected[i]))
        b_gradient += inputs[i] * (m_new + (b_new * inputs[i]) - output_expected[i])

    m_new -= learning_rate * m_gradient
    b_new -= learning_rate * b_gradient

print(m_new, b_new)
```

Getting:

```
31.952623523538897 1.7979482813813066
```

which is close to the expected 32 and 1.8.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it! 
How did you know that the learning rate needed to get increased slightly? By trying?

Comment: Yes, trying a few values to see which ones make the result converge towards a similar one. Also, the rate of changes of the parameters will help you understand if LR is too small.

Answer (score 1):

You should continually update your parameters, in every step.  Something like:

```py
for i in range(10000):
    m_gradient, b_gradient = 0, 0

    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        m_gradient += (m + (b * inputs[i] - output_expected[i]))
        b_gradient += inputs[i] * (m + (b * inputs[i]) - output_expected[i])

    m -= learning_rate * m_gradient 
    b -= learning_rate * b_gradient
```

(But I didn't check your math.)